# Find the spectrum of $Ax(t)=tx(t)$ where $A:L^2[0,1]\rightarrow L^2[0,1]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

The following homework is given to my daughter by her functional analysis teacher: Find the spectrum of the operator $Ax(t)=tx(t)$, $\,\,(0\leq t\leq 1)$,
$$A:L^2[0,1]\rightarrow L^2[0,1].$$
Only thing I know is that the spectrum of a matrix is the set of the eigenvalues of that matrix. But, there is no matrix here. I tried to create a matrix by $A(t^k)=tt^k=t^{k+1}$ where $k\in\Bbb N$. That means, $A(e_k)=e_{k+1}$ where I thought of $L^2[0,1]=\Bbb R^{\infty}$. But, then it turns out that the matrix is $A$ is a lower triangular matrix with zero diagonal and hence its spectrum is $\{0\}$.

Is my answer correct? Or nonsense? Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145678/discussion-on-question-by-bob-dobbs-find-the-spectrum-of-axttxt-where-a); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.